# Typescript - const name already defined in type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to use a TYPE that has the same name as the obj that I am declaring, but get the error `FeatureFlags is already declared` - is this possible, or should I just change the name of the type declaration?

```
export type FeatureFlags = {
  [key: string]: {
    name: string;
    defaultValue: boolean;
  };
};

export const FeatureFlags: FeatureFlags = {
  SOME_FLAG: {
    name: 'test-flag',
    defaultValue: false,
  },
};
```

Comment: I think the error might be coming from somewhere else where you are using the identifier `FeatureFlags`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name-shadowing is a no-no, especially if you're wanting to export both variables from the same file.
I usually stick to camelCase for consts and PascalCase for interfaces, classes and types.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion and explaining some good practices.